# Create Local Group Allowing Access to Removable Storage

Tags: group-policy, removable-media

We have several Windows 10 Pro laptops where Local Group Policy disallows read, write, and execute access for removable disks. We would like certain users to have this access. It seems like something a group could be used for, but none of us have any sysadmin experience with Windows systems and are quite baffled about how to go about accomplishing this - or if this is even the best approach. Any advice would be appreciated. We are currently enabling this access in the Local Group Policy editor, but this seems like much too broad a brush.

Answer (score 1):

**For Windows client versions**

You may enable or disable group policies from an Administrator
PowerShell or CMD, using the `LGPO.exe` utility.

You may download it from
[Microsoft Security Compliance Toolkit 1.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55319),
where you can get the file `LGPO.zip`. This file contains
`LGPO.exe` and its documentation.

To backup the "Removable Disks: Deny write access" policy,
use the following command:

```
LGPO.exe /b C:\Temp\backup1 /n "Removable Disks: Deny write access"
```

This will save the current setting of the policy in a new
sub-folder under "backup1". You may likewise save the opposite
setting under "backup2".

To apply a setting, use a command such as :

```
LGPO.exe /g C:\Temp\backup1
```

Setting the policy "Removable Disks: Deny write access" causes
an immediate remount of all storage devices.

If one prefers using the
[Group Policy Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ee461027(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
they can be installed via
*Settings > Apps > Optional features > + Add a feature*,
search for and check
"Select the RSAT: Group Policy Management Tools"
and click Install.

You will then in PowerShell run as Admin be able to import the
cmdlets with the commands :

```
Install-WindowsFeature GPMC
Import-Module GroupPolicy
```

---

**For domains**

This is described in the article
[How to Disable or Enable USB Drives in Windows using Group Policy?](https://woshub.com/how-to-disable-usb-drives-using-group-policy/)

The following is an excerpt from the section
"Block USB Drives for Certain Users via GPO",
when you wish a policy not to apply to the group in which you
have included the users that are permitted to access removable storage.

> You can use the GPO **Security Filtering** to make an exception in a
> policy. For example, you want to prevent the USB blocking policy from
> being applied to the Domain Admins group:
>
> 1. Select your **Disable USB Access** policy in the Group Policy Management console
> 2. Add the **Domain Admins** group in the **Security Filtering** section
>
> [image]
>
> 3. Go to the **Delegation** tab and click the **Advanced**. In the security settings editor, specify that the Domain Admins group is not
>    allowed to apply this GPO (**Apply group policy – Deny**).
>
> [image]

Comment: Very nice answer Harry

Comment: I do not have this tool on the laptops in question. Only the Local Group Policy Editor.

Comment: This tool is for domain administrators and this answer applies to domains. Are you managing a domain? Are all your users only local ones?

Comment: This is a standalone laptop; all users are local. For the most part, in fact, the laptop is never connected to a network. As far as I know, I'm not managing a domain, but that's really outside the scope of my understanding.

Comment: Un this case, the answer is negative : You can't have exceptions to a local group policy except within a domain, which needs a Windows Server computer managing the domain.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate, but thanks for your time and inputs. Is there another way to manage this? We run our application by way of a PowerShell wrapper script and considered enabling/disabling USB access on launch/shutdown within the script, but we haven't found a way to do that, either. If this is a possibility I will start another thread.

Comment: I have extended my answer to include client computers.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).